# What's the bad magic number error?

Tags: python

What's the "Bad magic number" ImportError in python, and how do I fix it?

The only thing I can find online suggests this is caused by compiling a .py -> .pyc file and then trying to use it with the wrong version of python. In my case, however, the file seems to import fine some times but not others, and I'm not sure why.

The information python's providing in the traceback isn't particularly helpful (which is why I was asking here...), but here it is in case it helps:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Normalization import Normalizer
```

Comment: Could you provide the code in which the issue is occuring?

Comment: And which version of python are you using?

Comment: And is Normalization one of your files or a third party one?

Comment: These are my files and I'm using python 2.5.2.

Comment: Hrm, okay, I think I must have been importing an old .pyc file that was left behind long ago when I moved the .py file, and so I could import the new version but not the old.

Comment: So, Noah, did deleting the pyc file fix your problem?

Comment: And, what was the first two bytes of your problematic pyc (if you still have it somewhere)?

Comment: I axed the old .pyc file, so I don't have it handy, but my problem was with the import paths -- I think python would have used the .py file to recreate the .pyc file if I hadn't moved it (is that right?)

Comment: This error happened to me when using pyc files compiled in python 2.7 on a Centos 6.5 machine (it comes with python 2.6)

Comment: My `PYTHONPATH` environment variable pointed to code intended for a different python version. `export PYTHONPATH=`

Answer (score 496, accepted):

The magic number comes from UNIX-type systems where the first few bytes of a file held a marker indicating the file type.

Python puts a similar marker into its `pyc` files when it creates them.

Then the python interpreter makes sure this number is correct when loading it.

Anything that damages this magic number will cause your problem. This includes editing the `pyc` file or trying to run a `pyc` from a different version of python (usually later) than your interpreter.

If they are *your* `pyc` files (or you have the `py` files for them), just delete them and let the interpreter re-compile the `py` files. On UNIX type systems, that could be something as simple as:

```
rm *.pyc
```

or:

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

If they are not yours, and the original `py` files are not provided, you'll have to either *get* the `py` files for re-compilation, or use an interpreter that can run the `pyc` files with that particular magic value.

One thing that might be causing the intermittent nature. The `pyc` that's causing the problem may only be imported under certain conditions. It's highly unlikely it would import sometimes. You should check the actual full stack trace when the import fails.

As an aside, the first word of all my `2.5.1(r251:54863)` `pyc` files is `62131`, `2.6.1(r261:67517)` is `62161`. The list of all magic numbers can be found in `Python/import.c`, reproduced here for completeness (current as at the time the answer was posted, has changed since then):

```
1.5:   20121
1.5.1: 20121
1.5.2: 20121
1.6:   50428
2.0:   50823
2.0.1: 50823
2.1:   60202
2.1.1: 60202
2.1.2: 60202
2.2:   60717
2.3a0: 62011
2.3a0: 62021
2.3a0: 62011
2.4a0: 62041
2.4a3: 62051
2.4b1: 62061
2.5a0: 62071
2.5a0: 62081
2.5a0: 62091
2.5a0: 62092
2.5b3: 62101
2.5b3: 62111
2.5c1: 62121
2.5c2: 62131
2.6a0: 62151
2.6a1: 62161
2.7a0: 62171
```

Comment: Thanks -- this didn't directly help me figure out my problem, but it's nice to know the answer anyways!

Comment: How can I check what pyc file causes the issue, I have deleted all pyc files but still getting this error.

Comment: Perhaps you need 'rm __pycache__/*pyc' now, because the pyc files are now in that folder.

Comment: Thanks! It was happening to me with: ERROR:tornado.general:Cannot load translation for 'es': [Errno 0] Bad magic number: '/app/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo'. In fact, it was that the *.mo was not compiled correctly.

Comment: More extensive list here: https://github.com/google/pytype/blob/master/pytype/pyc/magic.py

Comment: Excellent explanation

Comment: FWIW, I think you can always delete `.pyc` files. Unless I'm missing something (not at all unlikely) it wouldn't matter if it is "yours" or someone else's. `.pyc` are created when some Python module is **imported**. Note that this doesn't happen when a Python module is **executed**. It is just an optimization that obviates the need to perform an interim step before making the module usable. That step will simply be re-performed if the `.pyc` is missing.

I'm all ears for a nuance in which any of that is incorrect.

Comment: For me, this pointed me to trying a `git clean -xfd --dry-run ...` in this repo I'm working with. It listed a bunch of *.pyc that needed to be regenerated so I targeted my `git clean ...` towards those. The reason those *.pyc needed to be regenerated was b.c. I checked out a new tag that made the transition from python2 to python3.

Comment: FYI in Pycharm, you can right click on a folder in the Project pane and hit `Clean Python compiled files` (cf: [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cleaning-pyc-files.html)).

Comment: @JohnCarrell: yes, you *can* delete the `pyc` files *if you have the `py` files they can be re-constructed from. I was thinking of the case where someone ships only the `pyc` files, however evil that may be :-). I'll clarify.

Answer (score 71):

Deleting all .pyc files will fix "Bad Magic Number" error.

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -delete
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `find . -name "*.pyc" -delete`, as you'll have issues with spaces (and possibly with too long a command line) if you expand all the filenames to pass to `rm`.

Comment: IMO thats quite a dangerous script. What if a package was delivered with only .pyc files in order to keep it closed source? Oops, you just deleted the application.

Comment: Probably best to first run `find . -name "*.pyc" -print` and only then either delete the problematic files manually, and/or run the command above, after verifying you're not doing something regrettable.

Comment: @DanMantyla Closed source packages deserve deletion anyways.

Answer (score 35):

Loading a python3 generated `*.pyc` file with python2 also causes this error.

Comment: This could be a comment, not a answer.

Comment: @Kroltan yet it is damn good as an answer, better than the accepted one. Concise and to-the-point.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins At least in my view, this could be a comment on any of the answers suggesting deletion of .pyc. Even though this is one possible *cause*, it doesn't have a different *solution*, so this is redundant. Feel free to disagree, just my opinion.

Comment: @Kroltan The 'how to fix' part is pretty obvious here. The cause, that's what really interesting – at least for me – is. I did a lot of mangling with different python 2.x versions and never encountered any incompatibilities between .pyc versions. And this solution says it is python3 vs python2 problem - information missing in the accepted answer. Plus I love short answers (where possible) :)

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins, this solution may well say it's a py2/3 issue but that's only *one* possibility and, for that matter, one suggested in the accepted answer (paragraph 4) since its very first version :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo this solution says there can be other possibilities. From my experience it is highly unlikely to be caused by different 2.x versions. The accepted answer is way too long for me. Many unnecessary details. It would be much more helpful to say under which condition this error arises instead of explaining what magic number is.

Comment: @Antony, that's understandable. Myself, I prefer to educate as well as solve the immediate problem (teach a man to fish and all that) but I can see where you're coming from. Cheers.

Comment: @paxdiablo I appreciate your efforts, and I'm also fond of going into details much deeper than necessary :) In this particular case this answer was more helpful to me, nothing more than that :)

Comment: This was the cause for me (actually 2.x pyc's ref'd in a 3.x environment), specifically an unrelated app install silently updating my system's python path environment variable (grrr).

Answer (score 6):

Take the pyc file to a windows machine. Use any Hex editor to open this pyc file. I used freeware 'HexEdit'. Now read hex value of first two bytes. In my case, these were 03 f3.

Open calc and convert its display mode to Programmer (Scientific in XP) to see Hex and Decimal conversion. Select "Hex" from Radio button. Enter values as second byte first and then the first byte i.e f303 Now click on "Dec" (Decimal) radio button. The value displayed is one which is correspond to the magic number aka version of python.

So, considering the table provided in earlier reply

- 1.5 => 20121 => 4E99  so files would have first byte as 99 and second as 4e
- 1.6 => 50428 => C4FC  so files would have first byte as fc and second as c4

Answer (score 4):

This can also be due to missing `__init__.py` file from the directory. Say if you create a new directory in Django for separating the unit tests into multiple files and place them in one directory then you also have to create the `__init__.py` file beside all the other files in new created test directory. otherwise it can give error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\unittest\loader.py",line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ImportError: bad magic number in 'APPNAME.tests': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was not `.pyc` but old binary `.mo` translation files after I renamed my own module, so inside this module folder I had to run

```
find . -name \*.po -execdir sh -c 'msgfmt "$0" -o `basename $0 .po`.mo' '{}' \;
```

(please do backup and try to fix `.pyc` files first)

Answer (score 3):

"Bad magic number" error also happens if you have manually named your file with an extension .pyc

Answer (score 1):

I had a strange case of Bad Magic Number error using a very old (1.5.2) implementation. I generated a .pyo file and that triggered the error. Bizarrely, the problem was solved by changing the name of the module. The offending name was sms.py. If I generated an sms.pyo from that module, Bad Magic Number error was the result. When I changed the name to smst.py, the error went away. I checked back and forth to see if sms.py somehow interfered with any other module with the same name but I could not find any name collision. Even though the source of this problem remained a mistery for me, I recommend trying a module name change.

Answer (score 0):

This is much more efficent than above.

```
find {directory-of-.pyc-files} -name "*.pyc" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

where `{directory-of-.pyc-files}` is the directory that contains the compiled python files.

Comment: That is in case you have the py files on hand, if not you will need to downgrade the python install.

Comment: This is still unsafe for some edge cases. Also why are we doing a recursive delete when we're talking about files?

Comment: Why are you using two processes? Even if find didn't have delete, you could still run `find /dir -name "*.pyc" -exec rm '{}' ';'`

Comment: The 'find' command won't work safely for filenames with spaces in if the default -print final operator is used directly by xargs rm. Python doesn't import non-identifier named files like this, but scripts could still cause this to break and they wouldn't be deleted. Generally always safer to use an extra -print0 (zero on the end) on the find command (as the last parameter before the '|' pipe symbol) and then -0 option on xargs (thats a hyphen + zero) to understand the -print0 output before the rm command, when piping find into xargs.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you have the wrong python27.dll file (in case of Windows), to solve this just re-install (or extract) python with the exact corresponding dll version. I had a similar experience.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue with Fedora26 where many tools such as dnf were broken due to bad magic number for six.
For an unknown reason i've got a file /usr/bin/six.pyc, with the unexpected magic number. Deleting this file fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run this command in every path you have in your environment.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/source_code/src/python', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Then run the command in every directory here

```
find /usr/lib/python3.6/ -name "*.pyc" -delete
find /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages -name "*.pyc" -delete
# etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've `git clone` a lib which had an interpreter of

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

While `python` was leading to `Python2.7` even though my main code was running with python3.6 ... it still created a `*.pyc` file for `2.7` version ...

I can say that this error probably is a result of a mix between 2.7 & 3+ versions, this is why cleanup ( in any way you can think of that you're using ) - will help here ...

- don't forget to adjust those Python2x code -> python 3...

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same error : `ImportError bad magic number`. This was on windows 10

This error was because I installed `mysql-connector`

So I had to:

```sh
pip uninstall mysql-comnector
pip uninstall mysql-connector-python
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't delete them!!! Until..........

Find a version on your git, svn or copy folder that works.

Delete them and then recover all .pyc.

That's work for me.

Comment: eyyy why do i have -1? it really works for me and i was in really bad situation ¬¬

Comment: revert to previous version is not a global solution

Comment: Why would you ever commit your  `*.pyc` files?

Comment: That's the usual error. When you don't configure the git ignore file correctly. So i give the solution and then you must order your git.