# Bad magic number error persists even after rebuilding the .pyc file

Tags: python, python-3.x

When running a Python 3 script of mine, I encounter a "Bad magic number" error (while the script tries to import another module). At first I imagined it's because there are .pyc files built by Python 2. I deleted the __pycache__ directory and reran the script, but the interpreter still gives me the same error when importing that module. Any ideas?

UPDATE: To clarify, I should mention that the import statement in the script doesn't cause the error by itself. Here's the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../mvc/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    from property import Property
  File "/home/mostafa/python/mvc/property.py", line 1, in <module>
    from owned import owned
  File "/home/mostafa/python/owned/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from list import OwnedList
ImportError: Bad magic number in /home/mostafa/python/list.pyc
```

Comment: A similar question as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error. Did you check to ensure your import of module does not depend on any other modules or __builtins__?

Comment: I did check out that question. My script has only two imports: one is sys (which works fine since it's placed before the other import), and one is the other module which causes the error.

Comment: Perhaps try running `python -v script.py`. The `-v` flag will cause python to print out all the imports as modules are loaded. This may supply a clue about where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Have you tried deleting /home/mostafa/python/list.pyc? Assuming you have `list.py`, python3 will generate a new list.pyc.

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/sd0MZ5Rq) is what I get when I run "python3 -v test.py". I can't say I see anything that can help, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @unutbu That's it. I'm afraid I didn't read the stack trace carefully. I expected the .pyc file to be in the "owned" directory, forgetting that an old version of list.pyc existed in the Python path. Thank you. Perhaps, you want to post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The last line of the stack trace shows the path to the `pyc` file causing the error:

```
ImportError: Bad magic number in /home/mostafa/python/list.pyc
```

Assuming you have `list.py` in your PYTHONPATH, you can delete `/home/mostafa/python/list.pyc`. When you import `list`, Python3 will generate a new version of `list.pyc` based on `list.py`.