# Python 2 and 3, are the bytecode (pyo & pyc) backward compatible?

Tags: python, bytecode, backwards-compatibility, pyc

Python 2 and 3, are the bytecode (pyo & pyc) backward compatible?

can i execute python 2 pyo & pyc file with python 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they are usually not even compatible between minor releases (e.g. 2.6 vs 2.7).
However, since you usually have the .py files, too, python will automatically compile them for the currently used version.

Comment: +1. You can find an interesting answer about how Python pyc files are versioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error

Comment: They are a Cpython implementation detail is that it?