# Bad magic number while trying to import .pyc module

Tags: python

I have some problems while trying to import some module (compiled .pyc) in my program. I know that it compiled in Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297), I have installed the same version, but had an error "bad magic number" while trying to import it :(

Does anybody know what I did wrong?
Or maybe it's possible to change magic number in .pyc module?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error?rq=1

Comment: i dont have .py file to recompile it. I have only .pyc but dont know why python cant import it. Versions are the same

Comment: I found that this file is .pyo (first time i found it with no extension). Is any differents .pyo and .pyc files? Or they are the same?

Comment: `.pyc` and `.pyo` are pretty similar. They are both versions of python code that have been "byte-compiled" so that they load faster when they are imported as modules into other python programs. `.pyo` is basically a slightly more optimized version of `.pyc`. (For more details see [the doc](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the [answer linked by Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error?rq=1) explains, your problem is almost certainly due to different versions of Python being used for compiling and loading the module. You can determine the magic number like this:

```
with open('pyuca.pyc', 'rb') as f:
    print struct.unpack('<H', f.read(2))
```

You can determine your Python version by printing `sys.version` (it is also echoed on interactive startup). If you are using Python 2.6.6, the magic number should be 62161. If it is different, you will need to switch to a different Python to be able to import the module.

The exact same applies to `.pyo` files.

Comment: Interesting thing. The .pyc file i need to import has magic: C0 00 00 00. It running from .Exe packed with pyInstaller. Python version 2.6.6 (DLL). Maybe PyInstaller change magic and possible structure of .pyc?

Comment: Are those hexadecimal bytes and if so, how did you obtain them? That does not look like a valid Python magic number, which might be why Python is refusing to import the file.

Comment: This is first 4 bytes from .pyc file. I know it looks weird. Now i need to watch pyInstaler source maybe it makes correction of magic and over thing on fly while program get started

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by running

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -exec rm {} +
```

which deleted all the pyc files in my directory. After that it was OK.

Comment: ```find . -name '*.pyc' -delete```

Answer (score 0):

If your running python2 and python3 and removing old *.pyc files is too messy you can add the following to try to patch this python3 bug by adjusting the code loader suffix for bytecode files.

```
import sys
if(sys.version_info.major>=3): # switch byte files end extension on 3
    import importlib.machinery
    altsuffix = ['.pyc3'] # or some other ending that doesn't create conflicts
    importlib.machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES = altsuffix
```