# Scapy failing to import 'IP' not defined

Tags: python, import, scapy

I am having an issue with scapy importing into a python script. I am using python 2.7. Scapy runs fine through interactive view but trying to write a custom script fails, name 'IP' is not defined

```
import sys
from scapy.all import *

p=sr(IP(dst="10.1.99.2")/TCP(dport=80))

print 'success'
```

On my end, using ubuntu 14.04 with latest scapy installed and python 2.7 running that script shoots off fails for importing several different layers with errors such as "can't import layer inet: name 'IP' is not defined"

any idea's?

Edit : Solved : dunno what it was, but the py file being on my desktop prevented it from running properly. Once I moved it to a downloads folder, it worked fine

Comment: How did you install scapy? pip? or apt-get?

Comment: sudo apt-get install scapy -- which occurred directly after installing ubuntu 14.04 on a vm

Comment: strange, try to use "apt-get remove scapy && pip install scapy" maybe the apt-get version is broken? I use the pip one as it is newer version

Comment: Upon typing the command above I was told I didn't have pip installed and instructed to install python-pip - after installing python-pip and rerunning above script, it states 'requirements already satisfied'

When trying to run my own scapy script, it still gives the many "can't import layer XXX: name 'IP' is not defined" with the XXX being many scapy modules? and at the end says TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Do you have it installed through dpkg? do `dpkg -l | grep scapy` does it return? if so, try to uninstall it `apt-get remove...` and then through pip install it

Comment: also try: `from scapy.all import *` followed by `dir(IP)`, the latter should return something

Comment: the dkpg command resulted in python-scapy -- so I apt-get removed python-scapy then reran sudo pip install scapy

this installed scapy successfully

reran my script and exact same problem

If I ran it with dir(IP)
I get : NameError : name 'IP' is not defined

Comment: Hi, what is the same of your file btw... :) is it scapy? or IP? ...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610064/scapy-all-import-does-not-work

Comment: I am not executing it from within the folder that has scapy.py in it, nor is my file called scapy.py  -- just called new2.py and on desktop not user/bin or etc

Comment: sorry, that is my 2cnt, no other idea

Answer (score 0):

From what I assume at this point, the file being on my desktop is what was triggering the issue - might be user restrictions inherent on ubuntu - however, after moving the .py file outside of my desktop folder, to downloads folder - it worked no more errors