# Python 3.3 - urllib.request - import error

Tags: python, urllib, pycharm, python-3.3

When I try to run the following Python 3.3 code on OS X 10.8 in PyCharm 2.7 (or run the .py file with the Python 3.3/2.7.3 launcher):

```
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
print(f.read(300))
```

I get the following error message:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3 /Users/username/PycharmProjects/urllib/urllib.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1512, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/urllib/urllib.py", line 3, in <module>
    import urllib.request
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/urllib/urllib.py", line 3, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named 'urllib.request'; urllib is not a package

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The only way I can succesfully run the code is via the Python shell.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks.

---

I changed the filename to url.py, now it succesfully executes in PyCharm.

But when executing the file via Python Launcher 3.3 it gives me the following error:

```
 File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/urllib/url.py", line 3, in <module>
import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
```

Why is the code running fine in PyCharm (3.3) but giving me an error when launched with Python Launcher (3.3)?

Comment: Name your file something other than `urllib.py`

Comment: By default Python searches the current directory first for modules to import.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You named your file `urllib`, it is shadowing the standard library package. Rename your file.

Comment: +1 for submitting an answer instead of leaving a drive-by comment

Comment: I changed the filename to url.py, now it succesfully executes in PyCharm.

But when executing the file via Python Launcher 3.3 it gives me the following error:

     File "/Users/narekaramjan/PycharmProjects/urllib/url.py", line 3, in <module>
    import urllib.request
    ImportError: No module named request

Why is the code running fine in PyCharm (3.3) but giving me an error when launched with Pythong Launcher (3.3)?

Comment: I have no idea what "Python Launcher" is. Does it use python3? Do you have an `__init__.py` file? Can your project (it's also named urllib) shadow the `urllib` package?

Comment: On OS X the Python Launcher is the app that launches/runs your *.py file.

Solved the problem by deleting the url.pyc file using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error

Thanks for you help Pavel!

Answer (score 2):

In mac, VSCode is using Python 2. If you print `urllib` module, you will find out that this module is for Python 2.

So, I added one comment to choose Python version:

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846908/proper-shebang-for-python-script for how to set a good shebang line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it waw solved activating in command palette (shift+commant+p) **Linting: Enable Linting: on** and in VMStudio Settings (Preferences => Settings) select flake8 in Python:linter => Linter to use as flake8.