# change association for python files on mac terminal

Tags: python, macos

I have the anaconda python install on my mac and I already set the path for it. When I type in python in the terminal, it opens the anaconda python as intended. But when I use a command like "./file.py", the original apple python is used. How can I change it so that it would run with anaconda python as well?

Answer (score 2):

What is the [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846908/proper-shebang-for-python-script) at the top of the file?

If it's `/usr/bin/python`, it'll always use system python.

If it's `/usr/bin/env python`, it will use whichever `python` binary is highest on the `PATH`.

Comment: You are right. It indeed is /usr/bin/python. Thanks

Comment: Great! Remember to mark the answer as accepted :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer