# Executable .py file with shebang path to which python gives error, command not found

Tags: python, linux, unix

I have a self-installed python in my user directory in a corporate UNIX SUSE computer (no sudo privilege):

`which python
<user>/bin/python/Python-3.6.1/python`

I have an executable (chmod 777) sample.py file with this line at the top of the file:

`#!<user>/bin/python/Python-3.6.1/python`

I can execute the file like this:

`python sample.py`

But when I run it by itself I get an error:

`/full/path/sample.py
 /full/path/sample.py: Command not found`

I have no idea why it's not working. I'm discombobulated as what might be going wrong since the file is executable, the python path is correct, and the file executes if I put a python command in the front. What am I missing?

EDIT:
I tried putting this on top of the file:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

Now, I get this error:

`: No such file or directory`

I tried this to make sure my env is correct

`which env
 /usr/bin/env`

EDIT2:
Yes, I can run the script fine using the shebang command like this:
`<user>/bin/python/Python-3.6.1/python /full/path/sample.py`

Comment: Not a solution to the problem, but `chmod 777` is (almost) never the right thing to do. Set only the privileges you actually need. In this case that's most likely `755` (you get read/write/execute, others get read/execute)

Comment: Have you checked that you can run the script using the path you're providing? Instead of `python sample.py`, can you run `/the/full/path/from/shbang sample.py`? If yes, then the problem is likely with the formatting of the first line. If no, then either you're pointing at the wrong python binary, or the python installation is broken.

Comment: @viraptor, yes I can run the script using the path from shebang, I also added this to my edit above. The formatting is correct, I double checked, and the python installation cannot be broken because I can run scripts using both 'python' command and '/path/from/shebang/' command.

Comment: Any spaces or characters that would need quoting in paths?

Comment: @BorkoJandras, the path is basically this: `/abc/xyz/disks/ab.xyz.123/myname/bin/python/Python-3.6.1/python`. The only odd thing I see is periods and hyphens. The full path of the python file is also very similar to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file has DOS line endings (CR+LF). It works if you run `python sample.py` but doesn't work if you run `./sample.py`. Recode the file so it has Unix line endings (pure LF at the end of every line).

Comment: You're a lifesaver. That's it. Goddammit! I ran `dos2unix sample.py` and now it runs fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `#!/usr/bin/env python` as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846908/proper-shebang-for-python-script). Let the OS do the work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that but it doesn't work. Please look at my edit for more detail.