# best practice with 2 Dockerfile in 1 folder?

Tags: python, dockerfile

In 1 folder, there exist **a.py**, **b.by** and **util.py**. Script a and b both import **util.py**.

I need to build an image running python script a.py and a image running python script b.py

what is the best practice of this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run my python script on docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202705/how-to-run-my-python-script-on-docker)

Comment: do you want to implement 2 individual files or both commands in one single docker file? What is the role of folder here ?

Comment: Take a look at Docker `ARG`s https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/. You can use them to switch out variables. So something like `ARG script` then later in the Dockerfile `${script:-a.py}`. Then `docker build --build-arg script=b.py` to use script `b.py` instead. This way you only need one Dockerfile.