# shared volume with luigi docker server

Tags: python, docker, luigi

I am trying to experiment a bit with docker and luigi https://hub.docker.com/r/spotify/luigi

I created a docker container with spotify/luigi. I am quite new to this and this image does not seem to be accessible through the console.

I created a shared volume and mapped it to /luigi/share/ for the container

```
import luigi
import time

class HelloWorld(luigi.Task):
    def requires(self):
        return None
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('/luigi/share/helloworld3.txt')
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        with self.output().open('w') as outfile:
            outfile.write('Hello World!\n')
        time.sleep(1)

class NameSubstituter(luigi.Task):
    name = luigi.Parameter()

    def requires(self):
        return HelloWorld()
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(self.input().path + '.name_' + self.name)
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        with self.input().open() as infile, self.output().open('w') as outfile:
            text = infile.read()
            text = text.replace('World', self.name)
            outfile.write(text)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run()
```

This is the example Code I run with python test.py --scheduler-host 192.168.178.48 NameSubstituter

When I now look into another container with the shared volume there is no text file created.

I am a little lost here...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you run `test.py` directly from Python, you aren't actually running anything through docker. You need to follow the instructions actually set up your container with your `test.py` inside and then run it from docker. This link might have more information: [How to run my python script on docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202705/how-to-run-my-python-script-on-docker)