# Error Trying To Send Email Python

Tags: python, email, gmail, smtplib

Okay, I am trying to make a program that emails someone something in python, there are other things like this on the forum but i have made those changes and they seem to not be working, I think smtplib has changed, for reference I am using python 2.7

Here is the code

```
#sending email with python
import smtplib
TO="example2@gmail.com"
SUBJECT = 'Sending an email yo'
TEXT = 'YOLO'

gmail_sender = "example@gmail.com"
gmail_passwd = 'pass'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo
server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

BODY = '\r\n'.join([
    'To: %s' % TO,
    'From: %s' % gmail_sender,
    'Subject: %s' % SUBJECT,
    '',
    TEXT
    ])

try:
    server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [TO], BODY)
except:
    print('ERROR!!!!!')
server.quit()
```

After making changes suggested, this is y new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hack\Desktop\yolo.py", line 10, in <module>
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 321, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
self.source_address)
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 512, in create_connection
raise err
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 503, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because                       
the target machine activley refused it
```

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by the name of your script -- 'email.py'. Because Python has an [email](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html) package already. Rename your script would solve it.

Comment: That fixed one problem, still get                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hack\Desktop\yolo.py", line 2, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
ImportError: bad magic number in 'email': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

Comment: @DavidRichardson After googling I guess remove files with extension .pyc may help you. More details can be found [link1](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/importerror-bad-magic-number-in-time-bx03xf3rn) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I updated the post with more errors that come now.

Comment: I fixed it, it was because I had other versions of python installed.

Comment: @DavidRichardson Thanks for your reply and update. :)

Comment: @DavidRichardson You should accept the answer. This answer helps me as well.

Comment: @SmallChess I can't figure out how to do that, still a newb user.