# python script working when run in cmd but not when run from file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a module installed in to my python. I try to run it from CMD and it works but when I run a file with the exact same commands it doesn't work. any ideas?
[image: python outcome]
The top row is when I run the file and the file
The bottom row is when I run the command and the program that runs.
any ideas?

**UPDATE**
doesn't work also when moved to the same dir:
[image]

**UPDATE 2**
Also when I change the file name I get a traceback blaming a drive which doesnt exist (E)

```
F:\>python env.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "env.py", line 1, in <module>
         import Envyronment.GUI.welcome
    File "E:\Envyronment.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named GUI.welcome
```

**UPDATE 3**
when I run the code via pycharm I get the following error:

```
  File "F:/env.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Envyronment.GUI.welcome
ImportError: bad magic number in 'Envyronment': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Post actual code, and describe exactly what your error is with it. Currently it is hard to understand your problem

Comment: @SiHa the problem is not in the code its in the running of the code

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error) for the 'magic number' error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your script has the same name as the module that you want to import. In the working case, you run python in `C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop` and then import. Python finds the `Envyronment` module and everyone is happy.

In the non-working case, you change directories to `C:\Users\Isaac` and run a script called `Envyronment.py`. When you import a module, python (quite unfortunately IMHO) checks your local directory for the module before moving on to other python paths. It finds your `Envyronment.py` script and re-imports it instead of the system script.

You can test this by changing your code to

```
import os
import Envyronment
print(os.path.abspath(Envyronment.__file__)
```

The solution is to rename your script. Scripts should not be named the same as modules they want to import.

Comment: Already tried. When I run it I get a traceback:
File "env.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Envyronment.GUI.welcome
  File "E:\Envyronment.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named GUI.welcome

Drive E does not exist so I dont know the problem

Comment: You do have a Drive E! Try `cd E:` and it should work. Do you have a USB drive with a copy of your program plugged in? Notice that the system is finding an `Envyronment.py` but that file should be deleted completely.

Comment: E: is an empty drive

Comment: Perhaps the file is hidden? Other than that I can't guess whats going on.

Answer (score -1):

in the upper window, you are in the "Desktop" directory.  In the lower window, you are in your home directory.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the lib in the same folder of the script and it should work

Comment: Which lib? the module was installed on to the python

Comment: The Envyronment one, maybe try put just `import Envyronment`

Comment: import Envyronment works but I need the .GUI.welcome

Comment: After importing it, try doing this `var = Envyronment.GUI.welcome` and execute it.
Btw how this lib works?

Comment: Not very pythony :/ , how can I do a var without import?