# How distribute my Python 3 app in *.pyc format?

Tags: python, compilation, distribute

I developed a simple Python app on Debian and I don't want to share my code.
The user will be on Windows.
I tried to use py_compile but the *.pyc file is not working on the other machine (Windows), giving a Bad magic number error.
Probably the error is due to a different Python 3 version, but the code is full compatible with any Python 3 version.

So, the question is: how can I compile a script in *.pyc format that is not checking the Python version in a so strictly way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to distribute your app easily without too much hazzle, just use one of the multiple available [freezing tools](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/#freezing-your-code-ref), you'll get it running on multiple platforms easily without spending too much time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html. You can do something like this `python -m compileall file.py`

Comment: Sorry but I still get the error: Bad magic number in .pyc file

Comment: I've found this, I hope this help you understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error