# How to disassemble byte code fully?

Tags: python, disassembly

I am given a piece of python byte code written by others without the source file.

It can be run successfully. And I want to disassemble it.

The problem is that after executing the following code:

```
import dis

dis.dis(byte_code)
```

I just got the function name, instead of the function body.

In addition, if I try to import the byte code, I'll get some errors:

```
ImportError: Bad magic number
```

So, is there some way to disassemble the function body?

Comment: How did you import the byte code?

Comment: from _https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html_: `dis.dis([bytesource])
Disassemble the bytesource object. bytesource can denote either a module, a class, a method, a function, or a code object. For a module, it disassembles all functions. For a class, it disassembles all methods. For a single code sequence, it prints one line per bytecode instruction. If no object is provided, it disassembles the last traceback.`

Comment: The bad magic number is probably because you are running a different python version.  See the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error

Comment: @martineau I just save the code obj to code.pyc, and write in another python script: import code

Comment: @cdarke I have seen this answer, but the problem is that I have neither the source code nor the version. The only thing I can do with it is to run the code obj.

Comment: Luke: I suggest you try `import the_module`, then `dis.dis(the_module)`.

Comment: @martineau Is there another way to import the module? I've tried to but failed.

Comment: Who gave you the module, why don't they have the version and the source?

Comment: @cdarke It's actually a part of reverse engineering, but I have the problem just disassembling it.

Comment: Luke: There are other ways of importing, but essentially they'd essentially be equivalent—so I wouldn't bother describing them. In your question you said "It can be run successfully." How are you doing that if not by `import`ing it?

Comment: I just use the exec(marshal.load(file)) .