# Tflearn bad magic number error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tflearn

I am getting this error with tflearn:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aaa.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tflearn
ImportError: bad magic number in 'tflearn': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

I have found one solution which is to uninstall and, re-install.
But, it didn't work.
Here is the code, that I tried:

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
import tflearn.datasets.mnist as mnist

X, Y, test_x, test_y = mnist.load_data(one_hot=True)

X = X.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
test_x = test_x.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])

# Building convolutional convnet
convnet = input_data(shape=[None, 28, 28, 1], name='input')
# http://tflearn.org/layers/conv/
# http://tflearn.org/activations/
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 10, activation='softmax')
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.01, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')

model = tflearn.DNN(convnet)
model.load('quicktest.model')
```

Please, help.

Comment: You seem to have some bad `.pyc` files (compiled Python files). It might be worth trying `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete` in the `tflearn` install directory as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/514395/7738328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting .pyc files, worked.

> `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete` in the tflearn install directory as
>   suggested in stackoverflow.com/a/514395/7738328`