# I can't install matplotlib, error message says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html.parser'; 'html' is not a package

Tags: python, matplotlib

I followed the instructions from this [site](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc/blob/master/chapter_15/README.md), but when I get to this step:

> Copy the .whl file to your project folder, open a command window, and navigate to the project folder. Then use pip to install matplotlib:

This error message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
__import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
from pip.index import Link
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 31, in <module>
from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 39, in <module>
from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 14, in <module>
from .compat import sysconfig, detect_encoding, ZipFile
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\compat.py", line 85, in <module>
from html.parser import HTMLParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html.parser'; 'html' is not a package
```

I have Python 3.6.4 and the version of matplotlib I downloaded from this [site](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/) is matplotlib-2.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl (md5)

EDIT: After installing Visual Basic and renaming the html file, the error message turned into this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
__import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 11, in <module>
import cgi
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\cgi.py", line 42, in <module>
import html
ImportError: bad magic number in 'html': b'\xd1\xf2\r\n'
```

What do I do?

Comment: This answer has a good description of what causes the magic number conflict: https://stackoverflow.com/a/514395/4225229

Comment: excellent! glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure the `html` package is installed in your python-packages path:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html