# sklearn is installed, but 'sklearn' is not a package in my "sklearn.py" file

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I know there are several similar questions asked, but mine still remains unanswered.

Here's the problem.
I used the command `python3 -m pip3 install -U scikit-learn` to install `sklearn`, `numpy`, and `scipy`.
However, when I run:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
```

in my file, I got an error message like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sklearn.py", line 4, in <module>
import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model'; 'sklearn' is not a package
```

And strangely, when I run

```
import sklearn
```

everything is fine without any error.

In fact, I can't use any of the attributes of `sklearn`, and I can only import `sklearn` but I can't do anything.

By the way, I run my file on MAC OS terminal with `python3` command.

Comment: Does your PYTHONPATH variable have sklearn in it?

Comment: @fordprefect Checking now

Comment: is the file you're running named sklearn.py? change that

Comment: WOW, changing the file's name works(although there's a bad magic number error now)!!!how?

Comment: @ChingYiTsai magic number error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error

Comment: After I fix the bad magic number, @MohammadAthar You really solved my problem!!! THX!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

your file name is `sklearn.py` when you try to import stuff, it looks at that file, which (I assume) doesn't have any `linear_model` object.  Change your filename to something like `my_sklearn_sandbox.py` to avoid this ambiguity

Comment: Actually this is the cause. Props for noticing that :)