# ImportError: bad magic number in 'dateparser': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

Tags: python

When I tried to import module dateparser, it gave me this error

```
ImportError: bad magic number in 'dateparser': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How did you install it? How are you running the script where you are doing this? It sounds like the library is from a different Python version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the bad magic number error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error)

Comment: Could be a `.pyc` file from a previous python version: https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/854

Comment: Remove the `*.pyc` files.

Comment: This method is helpful, thanks @ Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually doing a clean on the pyc files solves this issue:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;
```