# RuntimeError: Bad magic number in .pyc file

Tags: python

I have a compiled Python script called merlin.pyc which when I run it via a bash script in Linux returns:

> RuntimeError: Bad magic number in .pyc file

I understand that this can be caused by using different versions of Python to compile the .py into .pyc and to the version that you run the .pyc with.  I however complied merlin.py into merlin.pyc on the same Python build on the same platform a the one I am trying to run merlin.pyc with. I complied and am trything to run the python code using Python 2.7.13.

Are there any other possible causes for a bad magic number?

### Edit

Please see below for output of `dd if=merlin.pyc bs=8 count=1 | hexdump -C`:

[image]

Comment: The bottom line is that the file isn't valid; how it *became* invalid is almost academic. That said, a place to start would be to show us the header it actually came with so we can figure out what its current magic *is*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the bad magic number error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error)

Comment: Edit output of `dd if=yourfile.pyc bs=8 count=1 | hexdump -C` (or similar) into the question, and we can see what the actual magic is, and thus which version of Python the module *thinks* it's for. That'll also allow the assertion (that the same build was used) to be validated.

Comment: Thanks #Charles Duffy please see question exit for output

Comment: okay, so it *does* start with `03f3`, so that really is correct for Python 2.7... can you similarly (albeit ideally as copied/pasted text, not a screenshot image) demonstrate that it's a 2.7 interpreter throwing the error?

Comment: Hmm. Thinking about it -- could a different module that `merlin.pyc` imports be the one with the bad magic? (That one itself really does look fine) -- one way to test would be to trace the interpreter with `strace` or similar tools and watch which files it loads/reads.

Comment: Thanks, Not used strace before, how would I run strace?