# Mac OS 10.4 app on Later Mac OS with Later Python version

Tags: python, macos, midi

I'm trying to run app that uses an older version of python on a newer Mac version.
The app says it works on 10.4 Tiger and I think it would be using an older version of of python on 10.4 
[mjb2lite.app](https://sixthhappiness.github.io/articles/myjazzband-2-lite/mjb2lite.zip)
The windows version works fine on Win10 as it includes the library also
[mjb2lite home page](https://sixthhappiness.github.io/articles/myjazzband-2-lite/index.html) there is a Linux version as well. 
You simply drag the text file with chords Blues #40.mjb onto mjb2lite.app and it will create a midi file in the same folder (you will see the error).

```
Name: Blues #40
Meter: 4/4
Style: Swing
Key: F
Tempo: 132
Chorus: bars 1 to 12 (repeat 3 times)
Sections: 1A
| FMaj7 | Em7b5 A7 | Dm7 G7 | Cm7 F7 |
| BbMaj7 | Bbm7 | Am7 | Abm7 Db7 |
| Gm7 | C7 | FMaj7 D7 | Gm7 C7 |
| FMaj7 |
```

Is there any way around this like getting Mac to use an older version python if this is the issue ? The developer is retired from the project.

Comment: You can always install an older version of Python, right? It's even simpler if you're using a tool like Conda.

Comment: I found a python installer back to 2.5 but 10.4.11 was shipped with 2.3.5, tried the 2.5 and still get this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error

Comment: How about finding a way to run macOS 10.4? It's awkward, but it might work.

Comment: I could make a WineBottler of the Win version. I tried changing the magic number in the .pyc to the current python version that didn't work. I couldn't downgrade python to 2.3.5 with homebrew or macports.

Comment: I’m guessing you’ve seen [this page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-235/) already?

Comment: Yes there was just a Windows installer. I got it to work using "wine cmd" in the terminal and used the command line on the Win exe.