# cannot seem to open python idle 3.9. Win10

Tags: python, importerror

tried re-installing more than once. tried opening from cmd and get the following error: [python error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvlz3.png)

Am new to programming so stuck trying to solve this.
things tried: re-installing (user only, all users), previous version 3.8
things i know: a previous software seems to use python files under 2.8 something.
any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can find your answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error), my friend.

Comment: You need to remove old .pyc files that was generated with previous Python version.

Comment: I removed the `python-idle` tag because no IDLE code was run.  You should get the same traceback with, for instance `python -m tkinter` or any other module.  Running in Command Prompt and showing us the trackback (copy and paste here is good too) is helpful.  But I don't know how you got mismatched re and enum files.  Installing 3.9 in `python39` should have started with a empty directory and loaded compatible files.  I would uninstall and delete `.../python39`.  Click the start menu entry and delete when prompted.  Then re-download the correct 32/64 bit installer from python.org.

Comment: hi and thanks very much for your comments. my main aim by the way was to get the idle 3.9 to work. i tried installing python 2.7 and it worked. so i bet that that was causing the issue. i think the earlier version of python was installed with the biometric time attendance software. would like to ask if my pc can work with both the python 2.7 (for the time attendance software) and the 3.9 (for python programming lessons)??

Comment: Hi all, just wanted to let you guys know i managed to resolve the issue by completely uninstalling anything related to python and re-installed. python 3.9.. it resolved the issue.. cheers. and much appreciated to the responsees which helped..