# The file has not the right magic number

Tags: ocaml

I have a bytecode, which worked previously well. Today, I'm trying to run it, I get an error `the file './analyze' has not the right magic number: expected Caml1999X029, got Caml1999X023`.

I try to switch OCaml version from `4.12.0` e.g., to `4.07.0` which might be the version when I built the bytecode. I still get the same error when running the bytecode.

Does anyone know how I could run this bytecode correctly?

Comment: Not specific to OCaml, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error) may be instructive.

Comment: Previously, to compile the bytecode, I needed to install pacakges like `js_of_ocaml-ppx`. Now, since I have already the bytecode, after `opam switch 4.07.0`, do i still need to install other packages to execute the bytecode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Re-posting as an answer what I wrote in comments.)

**According to [compiler docs](https://ocaml.org/api/compilerlibref/Misc.Magic_number.html), the part of the magic number after `X` is a number which grows monotonically with versions of the compiler.** So, to find out what was the version of OCaml when `Caml1999X023` was in use, you can try running your bytecode against various versions of OCaml, by dichotomy; or you can reverse-engineer the compiler by looking at the history of [this source file](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/8da8b7e0/utils/config.mlp#L94) or [that one](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/8da8b7e0/runtime/caml/exec.h#L63), which is where the magic number is set (I searched for the word ”magic” with the GitHub search bar).

I did it for you: looks like your magic number has been introduced by these 2 commits in April 2018: [1](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/commit/7c416d1c), [2](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/commit/c10b2edc). According to the description of the first one, your version is 4.07.0 — which is consistent with [OCaml’s timeline](https://ocaml.org/releases/index.fr.html).

I can’t tell why trying this version failed for you. I don’t know the answer to your question about `js_of_ocaml-ppx` (in comments).

Answer (score 2):

The error message looks extremely reasonable, which suggests that it is probably telling you what you need to know if you only knew what it meant :-) I don't know the structure of the bytecode magic numbers but it looks like a small difference.

You might try a few different versions of OCaml until its ocamlc generates the same magic number as your bytecode file. You can see the magic number of a bytecode file using `dd` (sorry I can't think of an easier way):

```
$ echo $(dd bs=12 count=1 if=m.cmo 2>/dev/null)
Caml1999O027
```

As you can see my OCaml version (4.10.0) is generating a different magic number from either of the two you're seeing.