# CMD doesnt work because of python fatal error : bad magic number

Tags: python, cmd, environment-variables

I have read that i am not suppose to change PYTHONHOME
but even after following some post that are solved i cant change it back to the right value

I have read that bad magic number is due to a marker saying for which python version a file is intended

now i guess i have a conflit

I want to use the python3.8 version of my spyder IDE but when it was working my pip did install into standalone python3.10

Weirdly enough when i run script on my spyder IDE it works

But in my CMD when i type `pip install something`

i get the following return:

```
 Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:\Program Files\Spyder\Python'
  PYTHONPATH = 'C:\Python\Python 3.10\Lib\site-packages;
                C:\Users\tlc_l\Desktop\Coding perso;
                C:\Python\Python 3.7.9;
                C:\Python\Python 3.10\Lib;
                C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs;
                C:\Python\Python 3.10;
                C:\Program Files (x86)\Chrome driver\chromedriver_win32;
                C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application'
  program name = 'C:\Python\Python 3.10\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Python\\Python 3.10\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Program Files\\Spyder\\Python'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Program Files\\Spyder\\Python'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Python\\Python 3.10\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Program Files\\Spyder\\Python'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Program Files\\Spyder\\Python'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Python\\Python 3.10\\Lib\\site-packages',
    'C:\\Users\\tlc_l\\Desktop\\Coding perso',
    'C:\\Python\\Python 3.7.9',
    'C:\\Python\\Python 3.10\\Lib',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Spyder\\pkgs',
    'C:\\Python\\Python 3.10',
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Chrome driver\\chromedriver_win32',
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application',
    'C:\\Python\\Python 3.10\\python310.zip',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Spyder\\Python\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Spyder\\Python\\lib',
    'C:\\Python\\Python 3.10',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ImportError: bad magic number in 'encodings': b'B\r\r\n'

Current thread 0x00001d7c (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error?rq=2) of any help?

Comment: No or at least with my knowledge i cant use it

Comment: You could try reinstalling python as that may solve your issue.

Comment: I did reinstall it

Comment: Hmm.. try deleting C:/Python and installing python again. If that doesn't help i don't know what will help

Comment: Why do you have both Python 3.7 and 3.10 on the PythonPath?   And it looks like there may be a third Python installation at "C:\Program Files\Spyder\Python".  It looks like you will be picking up dlls, modules, etc from three different python installations.

Comment: @StephenC i had upgraded it at some point from 3.7 to 3.10  ok lets change that
Yes there is 3 python installed 3.7 ,3.10 and spyder3.8 and i want to keep the spyder one
Yes exactly there is conflit between those 3

Comment: So ... fix your Windows environment variables so that you *don't* have inconsistent pythonhome and pythonpath. See if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `venv` (a Virtual Environment) if you want a custom, private Python installation.